# Append delimited text to Vim register when appending words

Tags: vim, delimiter

I'd like to append some words to a register in Vim.  But instead of the words being appended together with no separator, I'd like to add " - " between the words.

I am recording a macro to find the words and append them to a specific register, which is easy to do but I do not know how to tell vim how to append the text separator after each word when I yank the word to the register.

Does anyone have any idea?

qa - start recording macro a

"zyiw - yank a word to register z

For the next step, how do I append " - " to register z before finding and appending the next word?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to do something like:

```
:let @z .= '-'
```

before the next `"Zyiw`.

This could be automated with a custom mapping:

```
nnoremap <key> :let @z .= '-' + expand('<cword>')
```

Reference:

```
:help :let-@
:help expand()
:help <cword>
```

Since we are doing vimscript, it is generally recommended to manipulate registers with `:help setreg()` and `:help getreg()` so we can go with an almost fully programmatic solution:

```
nnoremap <key> :call setreg('Z', '-' . expand('<cword>'))
```

Comment: Thank you romainl. I tested your answer just now and worked exactly like I had hoped!! Thank you for taking the time to help!